# Can't determine range rows count

Tags: excel, vba, count, range, rows

I have 3 comboboxes placed on a worksheet named cbo1, cbo2, and cbo3. When the user clicks an element from one, my code retrieves data from a database and places the results in a range of cells below the cbo.

The Change event of each cbo sends its number (1, 2, or 3) to the routine below to identify which cbo that was clicked as well as its associated range (module level public variables). Those ranges are initialized in the Workbook_Open routine to an initial range of one cell, the first cell immediately below each cbo. That range will expand and shrink (varying rows, one column) depending on the results of the data retrieval.

In the routine, I create a routine-level version of the chosen cbo and its range, do my work, then preserve the range size in the module-level range variables for the next time we come back into the routine. We need to know the range size from the last time so we can first clear it before putting new data into it.

Here is my problem:
I resize rngCBO (local variable) to hold arrResults. In doing so, the data is properly displayed in the appropriate cells. However, rngCBO.rows.count always reads as 1, no matter how many rows are actually in the range. (You can see I've placed a msgbox immediately after the resize to check it.) This presents a problem for the module-level variables rngCBO1, rngCBO2, and rngCBO3, because when we come *back* to this subroutine later, the first thing it is supposed to do is rngCBO.ClearContents. But since the rows always equals 1, only the first cell below the cbo's is getting cleared. Any cells below that which contain data are not getting cleared.

```
Option Explicit

'Module variables
Public rngCBO1 As Range
Public rngCBO2 As Range
Public rngCBO3 As Range

Public Sub WBcboChange(intNum As Integer)

    Dim cboObj As ComboBox
    Dim rngCBO As Range
    Dim intR As Integer
    Dim intRows As Integer
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim intFld As Integer
    Dim strFld As String
    Dim intChoice As Integer
    Dim rstResults As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim arrResults() As Date

    Select Case intNum  'Determine which cbo has been clicked (intNum brings it in)
        Case 1
            Set cboObj = wsStats.cboWB1
            Set rngCBO = rngCBO1
        Case 2
            Set cboObj = wsStats.cboWB2
            Set rngCBO = rngCBO2
        Case 3
            Set cboObj = wsStats.cboWB3
            Set rngCBO = rngCBO3
    End Select

    'clear any residual data from the cells under the cbo
    rngCBO.ClearContents

    If cboObj.Text <> "(none)" Then 'the user might just want to clear the cells and not be asking for more data

        intChoice = CInt(cboObj.Text)   'the cbo contains integer choices

    'Build the Fields string
        For intFld = 1 To 5  'there are five fields, each name being identical except ending in 1 through 5
            strFld = strFld & "tblAllDAta.[fld" & intFld & "] = " & intChoice
            If intWB < 5 Then
                strFld = strFld & " OR "
            End If
        Next

        'the data being retrieved consists of dates
        strSQL = "SELECT tblAllDAta.[Date] " & _
            "FROM tblAllDAta " & _
            "WHERE " & strFld & _
            " ORDER BY tblAllDAta.[Date] DESC"

        OpenDB  'call the routine which opens the dB connection
            Set rstResults = GetReadOnlyRecords(strSQL) 'call the function that acquires the desired records
            intRows = rstResults.RecordCount
            If intRows > 0 Then

                'transfer data from the recordset into an array
                ReDim arrResults(1 To intRows, 1 To 1)
                intR = 1
                rstResults.MoveFirst
                Do While Not rstResults.EOF
                    arrResults(intR, 1) = rstResults("Date")
                    rstResults.MoveNext
                    intR = intR + 1
                Loop

                'THIS IS WHERE MY PROBLEM OCCURS (I think)
                rngCBO.Resize(intRows, 1) = arrResults
                MsgBox rngCBO.Rows.Count   'this is always 1 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

            Else
                'there were no records matching the query
                rngCBO.Resize(1, 1) = "Never"

            End If

            Set rstResults = Nothing
        CloseDB

    End If

    'preserve the new ranges
    Select Case intNum
        Case 1
            Set rngCBO1 = rngCBO
        Case 2
            Set rngCBO2 = rngCBO
        Case 3
            Set rngCBO3 = rngCBO
    End Select

    Set rngCBO = Nothing
    Set cboObj = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Try putting `debug.print rngCBO.address` before your MsgBox -- may show what's going on.

Comment: To your point, the Immediate window is a better way to view what's going than the message box. Having said that, after doing so, the addresses it came up with were as I said before: the address of the single cell immediately below the cbo. They're the correct cell in the sense that they're the first cell of the appropriate range. The problem is that the range is recurringly only of that single cell, while the data results it displays are typically many cells (rows).

Comment: You're not resizing rngCBO. You're just inserting the array into a range that's based on rngCBO.

Comment: rngCBO.Resize(intR,1) = rstResults("Date") **doesn't** resize rngCBO? I mean...it is the Resize method, is it not?

Comment: It returns a range that is resized as you specified. The missing step is to set a range to that returned range, like `Set rngCBO=rngCBO.Resize(intR,1)`. It's just like referring to `x*2` won't double `x` unless you do `x=x*2`.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I had no idea that's how it worked. I've never coded in VBA before...just VB6...so I've got plenty to learn. I think I grasp this, now. Thanks so much. After providing a Set line of code, the thing works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rngCBO.Resize(intRows, 1)` doesn't resize `rngCBO`. It just returns a range that you utilize in that line of code, as you have by assigning an array to that returned range. To actually change the extent of rngCBO, you'd do:

`Set rngCBO=rngCBO.Resize(intR, 1)`

It's akin to the fact to referring to a `Long` called `x` like `MsbBox x * 2` doesn't change the value of `x`. To do that you'd have to say `x = x * 2`.

Interestingly (perhaps) the `ListObject` has a Resize method that actually resizes it.

Comment: I thought I responded, but I'm not seeing my comment. I truly hope I'm not being redundant by posting this. Doug, you are absolutely right. Adding a line of code with a Set statement was exactly what was needed. And that was a stellar explanation (the x*2 example). Makes me feel a little silly, but I've only coded in VB6 in the past, so this Range thing with Excel is new to me. I can't tell you how much I appreciate your help, Doug. Thank you.

Comment: Feeling a little silly is a great way to go :). I'm glad I could help.